# File Upload : ApiController

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http, asp.net-web-api

I have a file being uploaded using http post request using multipart/form-data to my class that is extending from ApiController.

In a dummy project, I am able to use:

```
HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase
```

to get the file inside my controller method where my Request is of type `System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper`.

But inside another production app where I have constraints of not adding any libraries/dlls, I don't see anything inside `System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper`.

My simple requirement is to get the posted file and convert it to a byte array to be able to store that into a database.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code sample is from a ASP.NET Web API project I did sometime ago. It allowed uploading of an image file. I removed parts that were not relevant to your question.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

    try
    {
        var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider());

        var firstImage = provider.Contents.FirstOrDefault();

        if (firstImage == null || firstImage.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName == null)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await firstImage.CopyToAsync(ms);

            var byteArray = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not recognize any file attached to it. It does not go any further than this line above: `if (firstImage == null || firstImage.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName == null)`  This is the form that i am using to post the file:  `<form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="api/upload3">    <fieldset>
                    <input name="caption" type="text" />
                    <label for="image1">Image File</label>
                    <input name="image1" type="file" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>`

Comment: it worked. i am now caught up with the situation of not being able to capture the fields being passed to me from the form that is defined as multipart/form-data.

Comment: @user877247 - great to hear that this answer worked for you. With this solution in place, it should be only a small amount of work to store that byteArray in your database.

Comment: is there any way to capture form variables from within my post method in apicontroller class? the solutions that i have looked so far are extending default MultipartMemoryStreamProvider behavior.